# Maven does not add classpath to Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, maven, classpath

I have a maven project, that I'm working on Eclipse.

I use maven eclipse:eclipse to generate the classpath, but ... it NEVER adds the classpath on the eclipse project. I've tried the maven-eclipse-plugin, I've tried the M2Eclipse plugin, but it doesn't matter what I do, I can't get the classpath entries to start working. I have many build errors, even thought the maven builds the ear perfectly.

Any guidelines?

Thanks for any answer!

UPDATE: Here's my root classpath:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="core/src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="core/src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="client/src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="client/src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="junit_server/src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="initializer/src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="initializer/src/main/webapp"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="site/src/main/webapp"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="core/src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="core/src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="var" path="M2_REPO"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

UPDATE2: This is my .project:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>coreisp_back</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The setup generated by the Maven Eclipse plugin is not compatible with m2e/m2eclipse. If you want to use Maven and Eclipse together your best course is to remove any modification to your setup generated by the maven eclipse plugin and use m2e to import your Maven project.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what do you mean by "remove any modification to your setup"? Remove the .classpath, .project and .settings from my project directory (and modules)?

Comment: Yes. Ideally you should go back to how your project was before you ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.

Comment: Assuming you build your project from the command line without problems, that is.

Comment: Just did it. It solved all my dependencies... however, it also split my project by modules :/ Should I create a new maven project and bring them all together?

Comment: If you compare your Eclipse project browser with the underlying directory structure, you'll notice that the new projects are purely an Eclipse/m2e thing, so I suggest you leave everything as is.

Comment: What is slightly misleading is the fact that your aggregator project is shown at the same level as all the other ones.

Answer (score 7):

- Upgrade to Eclipse Indigo ( 3.7 )
- Install m2e plugin ( http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/ ).
- Use File->Import->Existing Maven Projects[image]

Comment: I currently have Indigo, I've installed the plugin, and imported the project. No deal...

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the extra source folders to the pom.xml with the build-helper-maven-plugin.
Then run

mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse

For example this pom.xml ..

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>artifact</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>client/src/main/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>client/src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Generates this .classpath

```xml
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="client/src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="client/src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
</classpath>
```

Make sure the folders exist, if the path is incorrect they wont be added.
Look for this in the maven log.

[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/artifact/src/main/resources

My team found the eclipse maven plugins to be unstable, opting to create our entire eclipse config through maven.

Answer (score 1):

This is relying on m2eclipse. When you do that, all your dependencies are handled by maven/m2eclipse, so your .classpath becomes very minimal.

In term of project architecture, you want one eclipse project per maven pom.
Each project .classpath contains only the sources, JRE and maven injection:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

(adjust depending where your sources are).

I suspect your many errors come from duplicate entries in the dependencies because you inject them both manually (additional .classpath entries) and through maven.

You'll also want to verify local workspace resolution in m2eclipse are enabled (should be on by default).

Comment: Update: I have a master POM, and a few modules. That entry is not on my classpath, but should I add it on the main classpath, or the module classpath?

Comment: Here, I've added this to my .classpath: <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/> -> this created the "Maven Dependencies" on the Build Path, but the project isn't being correctly built yet. Can't tell you the errors, since they're more than 10k :/

Answer (score 1):

By default the mvn installs are not imported into eclipse automatically.
So, after you run mvn install from the command prompt. Run the following command:

mvn eclipse:eclipse

This will import all the jars into your eclipse project and will update the classpath as well.

You need to execute the above command the very first time you add a new dependency to your POM and do an mvn compile or install.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the most voted answer, you can *still* be left with a broken project, no 'Maven Dependencies' (Kepler) and no classpath resolution.

In my case my local maven repository `settings.xml` got deleted when a third party SDK updated itself. After a restart Eclipse seemed to clear out the reference to that missing `settings.xml` file.

Once I put the file back and referred to it in Maven > Installations > Global Settings: `/home/username/.m2/settings.xml`, cleaning each project kick-started all the necessary classpath resolution.

For me, the resulting files looked like:

**.classpath**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

**.project**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>jemh-ao</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 1):

a problem I run into is after converting a project to maven I need to clear the Run Configuration as conversion does not update the classpath to configure maven-dependency classpaths.[image: Eclipse Run Configuration classpath should show maven dependencies]