# mvn eclipse:eclipse not generating .classpath file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm very new to maven.
I wanted to convert a maven project to a java eclipse project.

I ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on the parent directory where pom.xml is present.

The build was successful & generated .project file but .classpath file is still not generated.

Because of this, although I'm able to import the project into eclipse but still not able to configure the build path, add jars or clean the project as the option is disabled.

Thank You

Comment: Could you show us your pom.xml file? it will add more info.

Comment: Which version of maven are u using?

Comment: Version: 3.0.4. `pom.xml` is very big & for security reasons I can not share it. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe this question/answer is similar to your situation?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071470/maven-does-not-add-classpath-to-eclipse-project