# How to setup a Java Eclipse (Juno) dynamic web project with Maven for App Engine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, gwt

I am using appengine + GWT in Eclipse and have working code but wanted to add Maven to control jar files. What is the current suggested way to setup such a project?

I have found a few possible options, but non work for me:

1) create "Dynamic Web Project" and setup directories to fit with Maven  ... https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#gwt_with_maven

2) Similar to 1, with more steps [Java Dynamic Web project with Maven and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888068/java-dynamic-web-project-with-maven-and-eclipse)

3) use plugins m2e 1.3+ and m2e-wtp 0.16.0+   http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E-WTP/New_and_Noteworthy/0.16#New_project_conversion_participants

I have tried creating projects from scratch and adding Maven to a working project, but non work. Maven looks to be working as every thing compiles ok, but the deploy fails. Look like the Jar files from Maven are not being deployed.

Comment: I had a similar problem. This answer should help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8923782/1187246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Maven GWT Plugin](http://mojohaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/eclipse/google_plugin.html) could help you!

Comment: Thanks. Looks like there are 2 methods, 1) setup directories to fit with Maven or 2) use m2e-wtp. But both lack good quality step by step instructions that will work for appengine + GWT + Maven. Your link should help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by terminal:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

and make it compatible with eclipse with:

```
mvn eclipse::eclipse
```

(last command you may do in the project folder)

(If command not works, make sure than you have Maven installed with: `mvn -version`)

After that open Eclipse import and u have maven's setup project ready... For change things you can use pow.xml file

Hope that helps you